# Access controls within custom alert dialog in android

Tags: android

When displaying custom dialog box which is showing textView and EditView. How can i access these elements within dialog. Below is the code which is giving error.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                     string = uetd.getText().toString() + ":" + petd.getText().toString(); /////producing error
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .create();
```

---

```
public class listdemo extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final int DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY = 7;
    EditText uetd;
    EditText petd;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String string;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     uetd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
      petd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

    showDialog(DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY);
}
        });
}
}
```

Comment: as usual we can't see the error when you don't post it.... and where did you define the variables used in the line which produces the error (namely uetd, string and petd)

Comment: actually I am running the code in emulator which closes the application on error so i don't know exact error but i can say that elements which are accessing in the statement are not allowed in non UI thread. I added some more code in original question.

Comment: In eclipse switch to the ddms perspective and then the window logcat. There you see the console output

Comment: Error is "java.lang.NullPointerException" in  oncreateDialog box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning the dialog immedately with return new AlertDialog.builder....and so on....you should save an instance of the dialog by creating a class variable just like this

```
AlertDialog dialog;
```

Then you can easily access the views of the dialog within the callback of the dialog:

```
dialog.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
```

You have to do this because when creating the callback it is in a way constructing a new class in memory so when you call findViewById() directly it can't find the activity

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 uetd=(EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
```

after following line in your code

```
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
```